# Stream was not readable is caused when use readbinary

Tags: c#, sockets, binaryreader, binarywriter

I am trying to send a value by socket .So i have two parts in my project Client and server .

The client sends a value to server using this code :

```
  NetworkStream networkStream = socketForServer.GetStream();
            System.IO.BinaryWriter binaryWriter =
               new System.IO.BinaryWriter(networkStream);

            //------
            int messageSource = 0;
            int messageDesitination = 0;
            int interlockingId = 0;
            int trackId = 0;
            int trainId = 2;
            int direction = 0;
            int messageType = 0;
            int informationType = 0;
            int dateTime = 0;

foreach (Sensor LeftSensorList in LeftSensor)
                {

                    binaryWriter.Write(messageSource);
                    binaryWriter.Write(messageDesitination);
                    binaryWriter.Write(interlockingId);
                    binaryWriter.Write(trackId);
                    binaryWriter.Write(trainId);
                    binaryWriter.Write(direction);
                    binaryWriter.Write(messageType);
                    binaryWriter.Write(informationType);
                    binaryWriter.Write(dateTime);

                    binaryWriter.Flush();
                    binaryWriter.Close();
                    Thread.Sleep(4000);

                }
```

In server part i should read the binary values :

```
static void Listeners()
        {

            Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
            if (socketForClient.Connected)
            {

                NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);

                while (true)
                {                                
                    List<int> variables = new List<int>();
                    using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream))
                    {

                        int messageSource = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int messageDesitination = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int interlockingId = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int trackId = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int trainId = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int direction = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int messageType =reader.ReadInt32();
                        int informationType = reader.ReadInt32();
                        int dateTime = reader.ReadInt32();
                         reader.Close();

                    }
            }
         }
```

So when the client send a value i can get the value in server part just for first time ,when a client sends another values to my server i got this error :

```
Stream was not readable.
```

Why ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is caused because BinaryReader assumes that it owns the stream and closes it when it uses it. If you're using 4.5 you can use this overload [http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804(v=vs.110).aspx](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/gg712804%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

It should look like this for you.

```
static void Listeners()
{

    Socket socketForClient = tcpListener.AcceptSocket();
    if (socketForClient.Connected)
    {
        NetworkStream networkStream = new NetworkStream(socketForClient);
        while (true)
        {                                
            List<int> variables = new List<int>();

            //Hint : This Line
            using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream, Encoding.Default, true))
            {
                int messageSource = reader.ReadInt32();
                int messageDesitination = reader.ReadInt32();
                int interlockingId = reader.ReadInt32();
                int trackId = reader.ReadInt32();
                int trainId = reader.ReadInt32();
                int direction = reader.ReadInt32();
                int messageType =reader.ReadInt32();
                int informationType = reader.ReadInt32();
                int dateTime = reader.ReadInt32();
                reader.Close();
            }
        }   
    }
}
```

Comment: But i got this error now :Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.when i use using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream, Encoding.Default, true))

Comment: @EA I think that is a completely different problem altogether; however, this question will be able to help you I believe http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3752968/endofstream-for-binaryreader

Comment: Yes it was ,You know the size of message that i get from the client is 18 bytes ,can it help ?

Comment: @EA If I were you I'd put the binary reader outside of the loop. Then I'd use reader.peekchar() If it returned -1 then I'd terminate the loop.

Comment: @EA I think its more appropriate for you to ask another question.

Comment: I asked:http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24455105/unable-to-read-beyond-the-end-of-the-stream-is-caused-when-use-readbinary

Comment: Hi dear friend i implement the method that you suggest me,but i need some help how can i be in touch with u ?

Comment: Hi dear could you please take a look at this :http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24586648/send-binary-data-and-read-the-values-of-that-using-async-socket-programming

Answer (score 5):

You are closing the reader in the loop, which is closing the stream. The simplest fix is to either:

- move the reader *outside* of the loop, or
- don't use a reader at all (just talking to the stream)

However, if you *need* to use the reader inside the loop, you can use the `new BinaryReader(Stream, Encoding, bool)` constructor overload and pass `true` in the final parameter to tell it not to close the underlying `Stream`. By default, it is assumed that the reader will become responsible for the lifetime of the `Stream`; the `leaveOpen` parameter changes this behaviour.

Comment: whoops, seems like you beat me to it.

Comment: Thanks but could you give me an example of second method ,because i should use binaryreader inside my loop

Comment: But i got this error now :Unable to read beyond the end of the stream.when i use  using (var reader = new BinaryReader(networkStream, Encoding.Default, true))